# telerik radcombobox : C# lambda expression to get list of values of checked items

Tags: c#, lambda, telerik, radcombobox

At the moment I have to break down this simple operation in two parts, I am sure the would be a better way is hiding from me :

```
List<int> selectedValues= new List<int>();
...
IEnumerable<RadComboBoxItem> checkedItems = from checkedItem in cblMagistrateCourts.Items.ToList()
                                             where checkedItem.Checked == true
                                             select checkedItem;
foreach (RadComboBoxItem item in checkedItems)
{
     if (item.Checked)
          selectedValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item.Value));
}
```

I am wanting this to be done server-side only.

Comment: What do you mean with server-side only? *UserControls* are scarcely supported server-side. Which code part should be executed server-side? And which technology is used? WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET? Does this come along with any MVVM framework? We need a bit more information about your concern.

Comment: Dear @ebeeb, certainly you're missing the fact that I can do the same on client side too, using JavaScript and I already was performing it, but turned out the I was getting the values after the page had loadded and it misguided the WCF service I was using from within JavaScript. But thanks though !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
List<int> selectedValues = cblMagistrateCourts.Items.Where(i => i.Checked)
                                                    .Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Value))
                                                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Or perhaps `.Select(i => int.Parse(i.Value.ToString()))` to include values like "3"

Comment: @JensKloster, I agree about converting. Just added `Convert` in code. It\`s better, than converting to `string`, IMO, and he already uses it.

Comment: I think the OP asks for how to redesign his code. You still operate on the `RadComboBox` (`cblMagistrateCourts`), which won't be provided *server-side*.

Comment: @ebeeb, we`ll have to wait for comments from OP then, because I don\`t see anything server-side here. He just gets values from CB items (no data binding, I guess?).

Answer (score 1):

Convert the value at same time you're selecting the checkedItem...

```
List<int> selectedValues = (from checkedItem in cblMagistrateCourts.Items.ToList()
                            where checkedItem.Checked == true
                            select Convert.ToInt32(checkedItem.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thansk @NeWNeO but turns out, Where(i => i.Checked) from icebat's solution it more efficient as it narrows down the <TSource> sequence itself. Other than that yours is too close to exactly what I was looking for. :-)

Answer (score -1):

```
rcb.CheckedItems.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```